# How to use the enum when selecting type of operations

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am trying to create a maths game which has arithmetic operations such as add (+), subtract (-), multiply (*) and divide (/), where the user is able to select which of the one operations out of the four do they want to select. And I want to know how to use an enumeration for the four different type of operations so far I have only included

```
enum class Operations{
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide,
};
```

and I now don't know what to add after that.

Comment: Make an Operations variable (enum object) and let the user select one of the operations. You have to give some more information for anybody to help

Answer (score 0):

Although enums can create problems, in your case using plain enums would work. Enum members implicity convert to int. This can help in your case to determine which operation the user wants to perform.

```
enum Operation
{
  Add, //0
  Subtract, //1
  Multiply, //2
  Divide //3
}operations_e;
```

Next, get the operands from the user

```
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
```

Next, get the operation the user wants to perform:

```
cout<<"Enter the operation you want to perform"<<endl;
cout<<"Enter 0 for ADD"<<endl;
cout<<"Enter 1 for SUBTRACT"<<endl;
cout<<"Enter 2 for MULTIPLY"<<endl;
cout<<"Enter 3 for DIVIDE"<<endl;

//Take user input into enum variable
cin>>operations_e;
```

Next, switch over the enumeration

```
switch(operations_e)
{
  case Add:
   //add the operands
   break;
  case Subtract:
   //subtract operands
   break;
  case Multiply:
   //multiply operands
  break;
  case Divide:
   //divide operands
   break;
  default:
   //add default case. Not necessary for enums as they are robust
   //but a good practice mention the default case
  break;
}
```